# rsyslog ommysql filter by priority

Tags: mysql, syslog, rsyslog

I have setup rsyslog 8.16.0. I have Windows servers sending syslog messages. The syslog client installed on Windows does not allow for message filtering.

How can I filter only messages with priority err (3)? Syslog messages are being sent to mysql db:

*.=err:ommysql:127.0.0.1,Syslog,rsyslog,xxxxx

I have added the above line, but all messages are going to mysql. I just want err.

cheers,

sam

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, below filters and sends to mysql db according to message severity (error '3') using rainer script.

```
    module(load="ommysql")
    if $syslogseverity <= '3' then {
    action(type="ommysql"
    server="127.0.0.1"
    serverport="3306"
    db="Syslog"
    uid="syslog"
    pwd="syslog")
    stop
    }
```